# Interstitial ad black screen

Tags: java, android

i imported interstitial ad on my android application. but when it shows then i press the back button to remove and the screen stays black, i put my code on on create method , is there possibility to call it in different way. thanks in advance, so would you help me please i tried a lot but still black screen appears after i press back button to remove it, here is my main activity

```
interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {


        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

        }
    });
```